# how to pass selected value from selected page to next page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, .net

```
  <select id="one" name="age">
                                            <option value="0-50">Select Age</option>
                                            <option value="0-4">0-4</option>
                                            <option value="5-9">5-9</option>
                                            <option value="10-14">10-14</option>
                                            <option value="15-19">15-19</option>
                                        </select>
```

I want  to show text which user selected from this dropdown to next page

for exmaple :- if user select age 5-9 from this page and user have see selected age to the next page like "selected age is 5-9"

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Are you using a form with POST or GET? Or are you trying to do it in javascript on selection? Or using sessions? We need more details to be able to help you fix the problem you are having. Please review [**how do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update the question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we have enough information to help.

Comment: Sorry for that,actually I have a post form and it is a filter fields and i want to show to the users which they seleted values from filter page to next page @FluffyKitten

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the selected age:

```js
one.addEventListener("change", function(){
     localStorage.setItem("age", this.value);
});
```

```html
<select id="one" name="age">
     <option value="0-50">Select Age</option>
     <option value="0-4">0-4</option>
     <option value="5-9">5-9</option>
     <option value="10-14">10-14</option>
     <option value="15-19">15-19</option>
</select>
```

And then retrieve the value in the other page as follows:

```
let age = (localStorage.getItem("age")) ? localStorage.getItem("age") : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an onchange property with a callback function to set the value to a variable. Then pass it as params in the url or store them in localStorage.